# 3 pronged L shaped plug for a Samsung heatpump dryer doesn't seem to fit into the 3 pronged L shape wall socket, it's as it the prongs are too long

Tags: receptacle, dryer

We can't see what could be the issue, the dryer plug is 3 pronged with L shape and so is the wall outlet. It almost feels like the prongs are too long, it starts to go but won't go all the way. Any advice?

Comment: post pictures for us, is the plug 20 Amps ?

Comment: Pictures will be good to make sure, but possible you have a tight fitting connection, which is good.  Tight is good, loose is bad.  Could also be a mismatch of plug and outlet, which is why pictures are needed.

Comment: 3-prong dryer outlets with the slanted hot pins are very bad. They were banned because they kept shocking people to death. A heat pump dryer may not need neutral.

Comment: Some good photos would be helpful, as well as any markings on the plug and socket.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the plug and socket in question please?

Comment: Another example where location could be useful. Never come across 3 pronged with L shape. And, as often the case, lack of pics won't help.